# Rabbitmq msg_store_transient of a queue is consuming all disk space

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, message-queue

erlang version = 1:24.0.2-1

rabbitmq-server version = 3.8.16-1

Recently installed latest rabbitmq on Ubuntu20.
I verified that all was working fine and consumer was consuming the notification from messaging queue as required.

After approximately a day, rabbbitmq crashed as there was 0 disk space left.

After analysis found that around 10G was consumed by msg_store_transient, to which restarting rabbitmq solved the issue.
But after a day, it happens again.

Can someone help me further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is Fixed:

1. We had high number of Ready messages because of which rdq files was taking huge space
2. There was a bug in code, that was listening to only one queue not all.

Comment: I have the same issue. Can you please share some code around how you solved this bug?

Comment: whats are your values  for Ready, Unacked and total messages for a queue? My code bug was unrelated to rabbitmq but was more of configuration issue

Comment: I resolved the issue. I had a node api that was starting consumer and producer together at every request. Starting consumer at each request lead to several connections. So, after I started the consumer only once after the rmq node starts, and outside the node api, the memory issue resolved.

Comment: Great .. Congrats 

Answer (score 1):

most likely you are consuming messages without sending back the `basic_ack`, see for example [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html) the `ch.basic_ack`

What to do:

- check the unacked messages see: [image]
- check if you are using too many not persistent messages
- check if you are using too many not persistent queues

Comment: Thank you, I will work on it and see how it goes !

Comment: hello, currently values for Ready, Unacked and total are 95167, 0 and 95167 respectively!

Comment: Issue is fixed, posted answer below